# Is it possible to forward ldap authorization from a web portal cgi form to a directory in apache

Tags: .htaccess, perl, ldap, cgi

I'm working on a web portal where a user is authenticated by LDAP through a perl CGI form. The authentication process uses the Net::LDAPS module. When logged in, the system keeps the user's authenticated status and creates a CGI cookie and the user can perform various actions through the portal, mostly interactions with a database, until the user logs out.

On the same server there's a directory with some files. I want a user to be able to log in to the web portal and then browse the file directory and be able to download those files.

The simplest way I can think of is placing an htaccess file with "Options +Indexes" and ldap authentication into the directory, but that would require another login that's not linked with the web portal.

Is there a way to link the web portal cgi-based ldap authentication to htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that the user can log out and then no longer use the portal. But there is no portable way for logging out a user with basic authentication. They will be able to continue browsing the directories.

Instead of your CGI script that authenticates the user, you can simply configure LDAP authentication for both the data directories and the portal. Ugly, but it would work.

The better and cleaner option for you will be to provide access to the data directories not directly but through the portal only. If you use Apache's path info feature (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) you don't even have to bother about checking the path for malicious "../../.." constructs and the URIs will look very natural to your users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Guido. The problem with the CGI portal is that it also checks the user against a user list in a database to determine permissions for actions in the portal, so it would be quite a lot of work to change that. And since the directory I want to link to contains sensitive data, I can't use anything like rewrite with HTTP_REFERER or HTTP_COOKIE. Can you suggest a way of linking through the portal that incorporates the LDAP authorization from the portal?

Comment: I don't really get that. What I meant with my answer was that you should implement a little explorer/Mac Finder for these directories as a component of your portal. If the user requests http://server/cgi-bin/finder.pl/path/to/dir, you display an index page for `$docroot/path/to/dir`, and if they navigate to http://server/cgi-bin/finder.pl/path/to/dir/secret.pdf, you return the pdf in the response body. And your cgi script checks whether the user is authenticated, just like the other scripts of your portal. Writing that finder.pl is not rocket science.